# Transform pd.DataFrame in a list of lists while replacing 'np.nan' values for empty text ' '

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I made a function that transforms my pandas DF into a list of lists, so I can use it to interact with Google API, that is why it has to be a list of lists.

The issue I am having here is that I have a lot of `np.nan` values that I would like to replace for blank/empty spaces before they get transformed into a list. Basically because when they get into the list they are replaced for 'nan' strings.

I only want to get rid of those `np.nan`, and keep all the rest of the data intact

This is the function where I am transforming the DF into list:

```
def updated_values_list(df):
    updated_values = df.T.reset_index().values.T.tolist()
    return [[str(j) for j in i] for i in updated_values]

list = updated_values_list(df)
```

Actual outputs:

```
>> list[0]
['header1', 'header2' ... 'headern'] # this one is ok
>> list[1]
['val1', 'val2', 'nan', 'nan', ...] # my actual output
```

The expected output

```
>> list[1]
['val1', 'val2', '', '', ...] # the output I want
```

Comment: expected output?

Comment: @adirabargil Give me a minute and I fix it

Comment: change last line to ``return [[str(j) if not np.isnan(j) else '' for j in i] for i in updated_values]``

Comment: @adirabargil depends on your perspective I guess. The provided answer is much slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas methods can be very slow for simple tasks because of unnecessary overhead. As we can see: -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[6.5]*30000 + [np.nan]*30000, 'b':[6.5]*30000 + [np.nan]*30000})

def solution1(df):
    updated_values = df.astype(object).fillna('').T.reset_index().values.T.tolist()
    return [[str(j) for j in i] for i in updated_values]

def solution2(df):
    updated_values = df.T.reset_index().values.T.tolist()
    return [[str(j) if not (not isinstance(j, str) and np.isnan(j)) else '' for j in i] for i in updated_values]
```

`%timeit solution1(df)`

`1.92 s ± 96.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

`%timeit solution2(df)`

`284 ms ± 23 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `df.fillna`. Since your data seems to be numeric and you want to replace it by a string, you can do the following.

```
df = df.astype(object).fillna('')
```

You shoud run this as the first command inside your function, before converting the whole dataframe to your list of lists.